# Serialize only the data you need from json

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I get some data form JSON.  I can't change JSON, it is foreign API.  JSON...

```
"apply" : {
              "type"   : "submit",
              "form"   : "#pageForm",
              "data"   : {
                             "ctl00$MainContentArea$fld_offerCode" : "%promo"
                         },
              "submit"   : "#OfferCodeSubmit",
              "response" : {
                               "type"  : "html",
                               "total" : "#orderItemsDisplay .totals:last"
                           }
          },
```

or

```
"apply" : {
              "type"        : "post",
              "url"         : "https:\/\/www.4wheelparts.com\/shoppingcart.aspx",
              "submit"      : "#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnCouponCode",
              "contentType" : "application\/x-www-form-urlencoded",
              "data"        : {
                                  "__VIEWSTATE"                             : "",
                                  "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tbCouponCode"  : "%promo",
                                  "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnCouponCode" : "Redeem"
                              }
          }
```

I want save JSON to database, and use **"serialize data"**.  But parameter **"data"** ***constantly changing***.  How can I serialize parameter **"type"**, **"url"**, **"submit"**, and is't serialize parametr **"data"**?

I want to add to my DB this form...

```
"type" : "post"
"url"  : "https:\/\/www.4wheelparts.com\/shoppingcart.aspx"
"data" : {
             "__VIEWSTATE"                             : "",
             "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tbCouponCode"  : "%promo",
             "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnCouponCode" : "Redeem"
         }
```

So I serialize the data...

```
public class Apply
{
    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    private String type;
    @SerializedName("submit")
    @Expose
    private String submit;
    @SerializedName("timeout")
    @Expose
    private Long timeout;

    ....How data should look like???
```

Or am I going to need to move the another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it problem with help:

```
import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
public interface ConfigsBodyRequest
{
    @GET("config.json")
    Observable<ResponseBody> getResponse();
}
```

I get json without serialization, and than parse json

**//item - (String) content of json file.**

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(item);
 String required = jsonObject.getString("apply");
```

And now required is equal to String : `{"type":"submit","form":"#pageForm","data":{"ctl00$MainContentArea$fld_offerCode":"%promo"}},`

And i just save in DB this string, this is what I needed. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

dont add data in your model and that will be ok. i suggest you to use `Gson` library. and do as below :

```
Apply apply = (new Gson()).fromJson(jsonString);
```

`jsonString` is a string variable containing your json.

you can import Gson library by adding this to your gradle file:

```
  compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
```

Comment: i can't find - how i can get json in format String with help retrofit\rxjava. Are you know?

Answer (score 1):

If you need only few specific data,Can follow this

```
jsonObj = new JSONObject(strRequestPacket);
requiredData = jsonObj.getString("requiredData");
```

If you need to map to your entity class,then follow this

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
if(mob_farmerStatus !=null){
User user = gson.fromJson(strRequestPacket, User.class);
System.out.println("user:::"+user);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Apply
{
    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    private String type;
    @SerializedName("submit")
    @Expose
    private String submit;
    @SerializedName("timeout")
    @Expose
    private Long timeout;
    @SerializedName("timeout")
    @Expose
    private Data data;

// Setter Getters here
}

public class Data 
{

private String vIEWSTATE;
private String ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tbCouponCode;
private String ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnCouponCode;
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

public String getVIEWSTATE() {
return vIEWSTATE;
}

public void setVIEWSTATE(String vIEWSTATE) {
this.vIEWSTATE = vIEWSTATE;
}

public String getCtl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tbCouponCode() {
return ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tbCouponCode;
}

public void setCtl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tbCouponCode(String ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tbCouponCode) {
this.ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tbCouponCode = ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tbCouponCode;
}

public String getCtl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnCouponCode() {
return ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnCouponCode;
}

public void setCtl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnCouponCode(String ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnCouponCode) {
this.ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnCouponCode = ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnCouponCode;
}

public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

}
```

Comment: "data" constantly changing friend. If I do so. Every time when change'll json, me need'll change code application. :(